# Play framework redirection error

Tags: heroku, playframework, routes, playframework-1.x

While developing my test app locally (on windows), my App worked fine no issues.

After deploying to heroku (using git) and invoking a specific GET i received an error. spending MANY hours trying to debug issue - that cannot be reproduced locally, i found the area that causes it (by commenting/un-commenting code areas)

here is the code that **didnt work** on heroku :

```
public static  void  compose(){
        compose("");
}

public static  void  compose(String content){
        render(content);
}
```

after changing the above to:

```
 public static  void  compose(){
        String content = "";
        renderTemplate("Application/compose.html",content);
    }
    public static  void  compose(String content){
        renderTemplate("Application/compose.html",content);
    }
```

the application **worked** fine on heroku

here is the exception (the one generated from first code segmant)

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /compose
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: @69hmkdf00
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops: UnexpectedException
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.vfs.VirtualFile.contentAsString(VirtualFile.java:180)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:69)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:172)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:640)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:695)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:659)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at controllers.Application.compose(Application.java:92)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.vfs.VirtualFile.inputstream(VirtualFile.java:111)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.vfs.VirtualFile.contentAsString(VirtualFile.java:178)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   ... 12 more
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/app/views (Is a directory)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   ... 13 more
2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.vfs.VirtualFile.inputstream(VirtualFile.java:109)
```

routes file relevant line

> * /compose  Application.compose

## My Question is

- what did i do wrong (& why the change i did fixed it) ?
- and why it does not reproduce locally ?

Comment: That is pretty odd.  Can you reproduce the error if you run locally in `prod` mode?

Comment: The FileNotFoundException is for /app/app/views which is weird. where did the additional /app came from? hmmmm

Comment: @JamesWard I tried locally (in production mode) , did not reproduce.

Comment: my only guess is - that Heroku server/OS (Ubuntu if im not mistaken) might be the cause as it is the only difference i can think of.

Comment: just a guess, but maybe setting `http.path` in production mode could solve the issue?

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue but I can't get it to work locally.  Check out https://github.com/jamesward/playcompose and let me know if you can get this working in the same way you did before.  Thanks.

Comment: in what directory do you have your views in? there seems to be something related to incorrect views folder in your stacktrace

2012-03-03T10:37:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/app/views (Is a directory)

Comment: On the dyno they are in `/app/app/views`.  Did you see what is different between my app and yours?

Comment: @JamesWard sorry, i moved on to a different project. i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work fine, if you change it like;

```
public static  void  compose(){
        String a = "";
        compose(a);
}

public static  void  compose(String content){
        render(content);
}
```

Because it needs to reserve some memory for the empty string, before rendering HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In Play framework version 1.2.x render method source looks like this:

```
protected static void render(Object... args) {
    String templateName = null;
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0] instanceof String && LocalVariablesNamesTracer.getAllLocalVariableNames(args[0]).isEmpty()) {
        templateName = args[0].toString();
    } else {
        templateName = template();
    }
    renderTemplate(templateName, args);
}
```

As one can see, if first argument is a string, and it doesn't match a name of a local variable - it is interpreted as a template name. Thus passing static empty string as first argument is treated like a request to render a template with empty name - therefore "file not found (... is a directory)" error occurs.

Indeed having a local variable with any name and passing that variable as an argument should supposedly make it work.

Seems like:

```
String tmp = "anything";
render(tmp);
```

is drastically different from

```
render("anything");
```

Second call will explicitly look for a template named "anything".